# join two or more tables for partial text search using mongoose in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

we have two tables branch and city list and had listed them in a frontend table with city name. we have linked the city name field in branch table from city list table. now we need to know how to partial or full text search and get the city name from branch table ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [text-search-in-aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/) in this scenario.